# How to change the macOS system settings layout?

Tags: macos, ventura

After I updated my macOS to Ventura, the system settings layout was changed to a list as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: list layout of mac system settings]

Does anyone know how to change the layout to a grid as before (in Monterey)?

I want my panels back; the layout should be like the panels shown in the article "[How to Change the Layout of macOS' System Preferences](https://www.howtogeek.com/291958/how-to-change-the-layout-of-macos-system-preferences/)".

Comment: Sorry, you can't change it. In its wisdom, Apple has decided that settings should look as much like an iPhone as possible.  You can't change the panels! You can't change the width. It breaks Apple's own human interface guidelines. Numerous respected commentators have pointed out the shortcomings. But I don't expect any significant changes. Sad. (Some people like the change).

Comment: @Gilby Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: is it possible to tell apple to stop screwing this settings layout? So stupid and annoying!

Comment: What were they thinking with this mess? I'm a very recent returnee to using Apple due to Microsoft's shambolic mess of an operating system, and I've been telling everyone how refreshing it is to have an OS that just works... and then they pull this stupid stunt! Please can we have the Monterey systems settings back? Our lab has eight Macs, and after updating my home computer there's no way the others will be going near Ventura unless they sort this thing out. (Sorry, I think I should have posted this as a reply rather than an answer... not sure how to do that)

Comment: Yeah I hate it. Found your post looking if there are ways to change it/alter it via plist? Nothing so far.  Def not liking it.  You can't even see all the available categories like before in a nice birds eye view. Now you have to scroll like its iPad settings. Very annoying indeed!

Comment: Don't forget to leave feedback for Apple at apple.com/feedback

Comment: Use the View menu at top, it cuts down on the frustration.

Comment: Don't forget the Search option - which lets you see all the places for things (so that feature you lost - like don't sleep when no display is connected, you can find in it's new sub-section...)

Answer (score 1):

Sad story. You can not change it. Apple decided, that this is the way we need to see the Settings.

This is not a drill.